# selenium webdriver : input data NOT inserted

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is a text input box `Search for`
in selenium, i can first find the element, input data. but on the front end i dont see any data inputted

I am not sure why my UI doesnt show data being typed by the webdriver . no error in the code log

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\rahul\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32_83\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://testingapp.workspez.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("field_email"));
    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("field_password"));
    WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Log In']"));

    username.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
    username.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
    password.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
    password.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);

    username.sendKeys("rahul@workspez.com");
    password.sendKeys("Sujeet@19");
    login.click();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    
    WebElement generalInfo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='General Info']"));
    generalInfo.click();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    WebElement Contacts = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Contacts']"));
    Contacts.click();
    
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    //find search for 
    WebElement newlyaddedcontact1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Search for']"));
    JavascriptExecutor executor1 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor1.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", newlyaddedcontact1);           
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].value='searchcontact';", newlyaddedcontact1);
    WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root']"));
    search.click();
```

**how to access that webpage**

1.login into http://testingapp.workspez.com

2. username :rahul@workspez.com  password: Sujeet@19
3. click general info tab on top, then click contacts 'tab'
4. you will see the search for box.

[image]

Comment: can you share link of page so that i can go through and tell what issue is 
?

Comment: first you need to click into that field then you can sendkeys to that field .(is this auto filled option)

Comment: the send keys doesn't work. Please look at the instructions above on access the page under 'how to access that webpage' thanks alot!  @JustinLambert

Comment: your search for does not getting values because web is behaving like that i entered values but does not getting from keyboard

Comment: How are you inputing data into page , you told search for option does not getting user values right ?

Comment: @JustinLambert i am doing 'executor.executeScript("arguments[0].value='"+name+"';", newlyaddedcontact1);' to add value

Comment: //label[contains(text(),'Search for')]  have you tried with this xpath ?

Comment: @JustinLambert i have added in the full code above. u can try in your java ide, see if it works. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I thing You need to change you Xpath.Because whatever you write XPath this is for a label you need to write for input control so i update your code.

```
IWebElement newlyaddedcontact1 = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//input[contains(@class,'MuiInput-input')]")).ToList()[0];
JavascriptExecutor executor1 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor1.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", newlyaddedcontact1);           
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].value='"+name+"';", newlyaddedcontact1);
```

Please Try this code. I write in C# language.